# Python paramiko thread safe?

Tags: python, ssh, thread-safety, paramiko

I want to poll system status like memory load or CPU load while executing some command in parallel. Can I use one Paramiko client in multiple Python threads or do I have to connect multiple Paramiko clients? I cannot find any documentation on Paramiko thread safety.

Thanks for your help,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paramiko is not thread safe.

Some related questions:

- [Is it necessary to open a SFTPClient per one thread in Paramiko with multi-threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50421508/850848)
- [How to prevent my app from hanging when parallelising paramiko.SFTPClient.get requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58604999/850848)
- [Upload large file using multiple connections/threads to an SFTP server with Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66161206/850848)