# Error when attempting to connect to multiple sessions at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I have been trying to connect to multiple sessions at the same time with paramiko in python3, but when I do this it throws this error

**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "API.py", line 12, in connect
    ssh.connect(f"{server}",port=22, username="root", password="x", tim
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 435, in
    self._auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 764, in
    raise saved_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 751, in
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1498
    raise SSHException("No existing session")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session**
```

I ran the script a couple of times, and it seems to be random which server it fails to connect to, here is my code.

```
    import paramiko
    import threading
    import time
    threads = []
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    API_servers =  ["x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x"]
    
    def connect(server):
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(f"{server}",port=22, username="root", password="x", look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, timeout=6000)
        ssh.exec_command(f"echo Connected to server! > debug.txt")
    
    for server in API_servers:
        t = threading.Thread(target=connect, args=(server,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
        time.sleep(.4)
    
    
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

I have searched on google for hours and still no help, thanks in advance.

Comment: about 4,. and i have tried the log thing but it doesnt seem to write to the file.

Comment: My best guess is simply that paramiko.SSHClient() is not thread-safe. It may be inefficient but as a test, move *ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()* inside the *connect()* function. I'm also guessing that if you only have one item in your *API_servers* list that it works

Comment: @BrutusForcus is right. I've overlooked that. I trusted you when you wrote that you *"connect to multiple sessions"*. But you do not. You connect *one session* and you are trying to use it from multiple threads. See [Python paramiko thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67635642/850848)

Comment: I will go ahead and try moving ```ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()``` into the connect function now.

Comment: Moving ```ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()``` to the connect functions Seems to have worked, thanks!