# Paramiko request_port_forward with and without handler

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

### TLDR:

can't read data from incoming paramiko port forwarding connections when using callbacks.
See this gist for a demonstration:
https://gist.github.com/tatome/0d3e6479f35b25bbb31c9f94610eab6b

*The gist also demonstrates the solution to the problem.*

### Detailed Question:

There's an example script that demonstrates how to use paramiko to set up a reverse tunnel [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/rforward.py).

The script requests port forwarding and then keeps `accept`ing connections in the main thread, and delegates handling these connections to another thread:

```py
transport.request_port_forward("", server_port)
while True:
    chan = transport.accept(1000)
    if chan is None:
        continue
    thr = threading.Thread(
        target=handler, args=(chan, remote_host, remote_port)
    )
```

Unfortunately, with this method, we don't know which port an incoming connection accessed, so we can't have multiple tunnels on different server ports that we treat differently.

However, we can pass a `handler` argument to `request_port_forward`, and `handler` does get the host name and port that the client accessed:

```py
def handler(channel, source_address, target_address):
    target_host, target_port = target_address
    ...

client.get_transport().request_port_forward('', port, handler)
```

**Here's the problem:** For some reason, the channel retrieved via `transport.accept()` and the channel passed to `handler` behave differently for me.

When I do this:

```py
client.connect(
    'localhost',
    22,
    username=USER,
    look_for_keys=True
)

def handler(channel, source_address, target_address):
    print("Selecting...")
    selects = select.select([channel],[],[])
    print("Selected: " + str(selects))

transport = client.get_transport()
p = transport.request_port_forward('', 30000)
print(p)
channel = transport.accept(1000)
handler(channel, None, None)
```

and then, on a shell:

```bash
wget localhost:30000
```

I get this:

```
30000
Selecting...
Selected: ([<paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 in-buffer=130 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x43b80fd0 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>], [], [])
```

If I pass the handler to `request_port_forward`, however, like this:

```py
def handler(channel, source_address, target_address):
    print("Selecting...")
    selects = select.select([channel],[],[])
    print("Selected: " + str(selects))

transport = client.get_transport()
transport.request_port_forward('', 30000, handler)
```

I get this:

```
Selecting...
```

and when I debug the script it will stop in the line that says `selects = select.select([channel],[],[])`.

`wget` says it sent the HTTP request, but my script never reads anything from the connection.

**Questions:**

- What am I doing wrong?
- Why does `select.select([channel])` does something else, depending on whether it's returned by `transport.accept()` or passed to the handler?
- How can you use the same transport for multiple different reverse tunnels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect this to be some threading issue. The difference between the two codes is that in the first, the `handler` is called on the main thread, while in the second, the `handler` is called on another thread. I do not think that [Paramiko is thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67635642/850848).

What I would try is to use `handler` only to notify the main thread loop (after `request_port_forward`) that a tunnel was opened and let it process it.

Quick and dirty code (just to test if I'm right or not)

```
tunnel_channel = None

def handler(channel, source_address, target_address):
    global tunnel_channel
    print("Tunnel opened.")
    tunnel_channel = channel

transport = client.get_transport()
transport.request_port_forward('', 30000, handler)

while True:
    if tunnel_channel != None:
        channel = tunnel_channel
        tunnel_channel = None
        print("Selecting...")
        selects = select.select([channel],[],[])
        print("Selected: " + str(selects))

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That did it. I didn't think that could be the problem because the example script for reverse tunneling also uses threads, but the threads processing the requests are started from the main thread when requests arrive, so outside of paramiko.
I added an MWE to my gist which demonstrates how to open multiple tunnels and process them concurrently:
https://gist.github.com/tatome/0d3e6479f35b25bbb31c9f94610eab6b#file-paramiko_port_forward_with_handler-py